# Pandas groupby mean issue

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, nan

I am trying to find the mean by event for each round (R1,R2,R3,R4). 
The rounds not played are unfortunately represented in 3 different ways (0, - or empty cell).

```
    event   plyr    R1  R2  R3  R4
0   Houston Dave    67  90.0    70  72
1   Houston Bobx    69  69.0    69  69
2   Houston Carlx   69  71.0    71  71
3   Miamixx Cliff   67  70.0    70  70
4   Miamixx Dean    70  71.0    71  71
5   Miamixx Clive   69  69.0    -   0
6   Miamixx Patxx   71  70.0    -   0
7   Atlanta Phil    67  70.0    70  72
8   Atlanta Dave    69  NaN 71  73
9   Atlanta Bobx    69  NaN -   0
```

I have tried replacing the 0 and - with NaN but still get varying results

df['R3'] = df['R3'].replace(['0', '-'], np.nan)
df['R4'] = df['R4'].replace(['0', '-'], np.nan)

The results

```
df.groupby('event')['R1','R2', 'R3', 'R4'].mean()


R1  R2  R4
event           
Atlanta 68.333333   70.000000   48.333333
Houston 68.333333   76.666667   70.666667
Miamixx 69.250000   70.000000   35.250000
```

Comment: Your 'R3' dtype is object, you need to convert it to a numeric dtype then try that statement again.

Comment: `df[df.columns[2:]].replace('-', 0).astype('float').groupby(df['event']).mean()`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out float was needed - i had tried ('int') but that would not work. For my own curiosity - any idea why float is needed when none of the values had decimal places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `groupby` mean aggregation will exclude `NaN` values but include zeros. So you need to replace by `0` or keep the `NaN` depending on the result you're after.

This will set all the `-` and `NaN` values to `0`:

```
cols = ['R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4']

for col in cols:
    df[col] = np.where((df[col]=='-') | (df[col].isnull()==True), 0, df[col])
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col])

df.groupby('event').mean()
```

If you want `NaN` instead of `0` simply replace the `0` in `np.where()` with `np.NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

#### `to_csv`/`read_csv`

Read the `csv` with appropriate `NaN` values specified then `fillna` with `0`

```
from io import StringIO as io_
df = pd.read_csv(io_(df.to_csv(index=False)), na_values=['-']).fillna(0)

df.groupby('event')[['R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4']].mean()

                R1         R2     R3         R4
event                                          
Atlanta  68.333333  23.333333  47.00  48.333333
Houston  68.333333  76.666667  70.00  70.666667
Miamixx  69.250000  70.000000  35.25  35.250000
```

---

#### `pd.to_numeric`

```
df.filter(like='R').apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce') \
  .fillna(0).groupby(df.event).mean()

                R1         R2     R3         R4
event                                          
Atlanta  68.333333  23.333333  47.00  48.333333
Houston  68.333333  76.666667  70.00  70.666667
Miamixx  69.250000  70.000000  35.25  35.250000
```